# ApiPlatform/Symfony - Generate path for resources

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I like to generate the uri for an APiPlatform resource, which seems pretty elementary to me, but I can't seem to find out how. This is what I'd like to accomplish:

Given the resource definition below I'd like get the url based on the resource class name, operation type and operation name.

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={"GET"},
 *     collectionOperations={"GET"}
 * )
 */
class Customer
{
    // ... 
}
```

```php
$path = $someApiPlatformService->getOperationPath(Customer::class, ApiPlatform\Core\Api\OperationType::COLLECTION, 'GET');
```

Expected value of path would be `/api/customers`.

```php
$itemId = 'someid';
$path = $someApiPlatformService->getOperationPath(Customer::class, ApiPlatform\Core\Api\OperationType::ITEM, 'GET', $itemId);
```

Expected value of path would be `/api/customers/someid`.

Answer (score 4):

**ABOUT URL GENERATION**

Your problem is mostly handled by the **[IriConverterInterface](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/Api/IriConverterInterface.php)::getIriFromResourceClass()** method. This is api-platform core service to convert URLs to entities and entities to URLs.

Howewer, it does not use the operation name because as explained [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/) :

> By default, API Platform uses the first GET operation defined in itemOperations to generate the IRI of an item and the first GET operation defined in collectionOperations to generate the IRI of a collection

**PARTIAL SOLUTION**

Since **IriConverterInterface** is not enough, you need to

1. calculate your route name, *for example* with the internal (i.e forbidden, i don't know what service to use for now, but I guess it is an interface within the Routing namespace) **[RouteNameGenerator](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/Bridge/Symfony/Routing/RouteNameGenerator.php)::generate()**,
2. then pass it to the **[UrlGeneratorInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGeneratorInterface.php)::generate()** method, as explained by Symfony [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-urls-in-services)

```
$resourceNameAsArray = explode('\\', Customer::class);
$resourceShortName = $resourceNameAsArray[count($resourceNameAsArray) -1];
$routeName = ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\RouteNameGenerator::generate('GET', $resourceShortName, ApiPlatform\Core\Api\OperationType::COLLECTION);
$path = $urlGenerator->generate($routeName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also dug a bit deeper into the internals of api-platform/core after posting this question and found the same classes/methods you describe. It seems a bit of a detour though, especially because of the internal RouteNameGenerator class. I'm still hoping to find a more straight forward way :) If not, your way might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

In **api-platform/core:3.1**:

```
class UrlGenerator
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly ResourceMetadataCollectionFactoryInterface $resourceMetadataCollectionFactory,
        private readonly RouterInterface $router,
    ) {
    }

    public function getAllUrlsForResource(string $resourceClass): array
    {
        $urls = [];

        foreach ($this->resourceMetadataCollectionFactory->create($resourceClass) as $resourceMetadata) {
            foreach ($resourceMetadata->getOperations() as $operation) {
                $urls[] = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get($operation->getName())->getPath();
            }
        }

        return $urls;
    }
}
```